# Need to submit a form without the onsubmit and include the action

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, form-submit

Here is a form

```
<cfoutput>
<form name    = "xrefform" 
    id        = "xrefform"
    action    = ""
    method    = "post"         
    onsubmit  = "return submitx('#coltop#', '#col#')">
</cfoutput>
```

There are two different way to submit it:
1) when you want the data in the form to be placed in a MySql Table
2) when you want the data to be deleted from the Mysql Table

For the first case I have

```
<input type     = "Submit"
        name    = "SubmitXref" 
        class   = "submitbut" 
        value   = "Submit"            
        onclick = "aasubmit('xref2.cfm')">
```

with corresponding javascript:

```
 function aasubmit(target) {
   document.xrefform.action = target;
 }//end function aasubmit
```

This works fine.

For the delete case I have

```
<input   type    = "Submit"
         id      = "delbut" 
         class   = "onoffbut" 
         value   = "delete"             
         onclick = "aasubmit('repdel.cfm')">
```

This has a problem, which is that the submitx() javascript runs, and in this case I don't want it to.

I find references that say using the document.form.submit() method will avoid running the onsubmit function.  But I can't figure out how to indicate the action.

Can someone show me how to do this?

---

After fussing around some more I found the answer:

For the delete button --which needs to evade the onsubmit script --here is the HTML:

```
   <input type    = "button"
        id      = "delbut"              
        value   = "Delete this item"
        onclick = "buttonsubmit('xrefdel.cfm', 'xrefform')">
```

And here is the javascript.

```
function buttonsubmit(target, source) {
var q = document.getElementById(source);  
q.action = target;
q.submit();
}
```

This works perfectly.  The ordinary submit honors the onsubmit script, the delete button skips it.

Comment: Just have one submit button on your form.  Use a dropdown or radio buttons as user input for what action is to be taken.

Comment: How does this help me avoid the onsubmit script?

Comment: Don't use any javascript at all.  Use ColdFusion code to read the form variables and do what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Let's outline your requirements:

1. One form
2. Two submit buttons
3. No JavaScript submit.

If you give each of the submit buttons a `name`, then you can have a single action page and check which button was clicked.

`name="doUpdate"` or `name="doDelete"`

The only name key that will exist in the form scope is whichever submit button was clicked. Use `structKeyExists()` to check and process accordingly.

Of course, you probably want to use `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` to call a validation function. If you click on "delete", you might want the user to confirm that was what they wanted to do before processing it. The function `validateForm()` just needs to return `true` or `false`, so you'll still avoid the JavaScript `submit()`.

Comment: Don't forget that forms can be submitted by pressing the enter key when certain form fields are in focus.  The relevance is that the submit field posted might not be the one the user had in mind.

Comment: I believe you have not understood my needs.  One form, two submits, one should run the onsubmit = abc() which is specified in the form.  The other should not run that script.  I don't care whether the second submit is via javascript, but I don't see how to avoid the second onsubmit = .

Comment: The function `submixt` will run when you submit the form no matter how you submit the form.  You can't avoid it.  You choices are to either modify it so that it knows which submit control was activated or to apply the logic in that function in another manner.  The latter approach strikes me as the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in the form:

```
<input name="action" value="save" id="action" type="hidden"> 
<button type="submit" class="button button-basic-green" onclick="document.getElementById('action').value='save';"><span class="fa fa-save"></span> Save</button>
<button type="submit" class="button button-basic" onclick="document.getElementById('action').value='reload';"><span class="fa fa-repeat"></span> Save &amp; Reload</button>         
<button type="submit" class="button button-basic" onclick="document.location.href='./';return false;"><span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></span> Cancel</button>
```

Note the default action of "save". Gets you something like:
[image]

Then in the singular form-action page, check to see what the form.action is and process accordingly.

```
<cfif form.action eq "reload">
    <cfset loc="page.cfm?id=#form.id#">
<cfelse>
    <cfset loc="./">
</cfif>
```